# Rhine paradox - discrepancies

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the Rhine paradox described [here](https://paginas.fe.up.pt/~ec/files_0910/slides/aula_1_IntroDM.pdf), the author arrives at a probability of 0.98 that at least 1 in 1,000 people would guess at ten cards right.

My calculations seem to produce a different result. This is how I did it:

$\text{P(at least one person getting all 10 cards right)} \\
  = 1 - \text{P(no person getting all 10 cards right)} \\
  = 1 - \text{P(person 1 not getting all cards right} \\ \text{* person 2 not getting all cards right *}\ldots \\ \text{* person 1000 not getting all cards right)} \\
  = 1 - (((2^{10})-1/(2^{10})) * ((2^{10})-1/(2^{10})) * \ldots * ((2^{10})-1/(2^{10}))) \\
  = 1 - ((0.9990234375)^{1000}) \\
  = 1 - 0.37642379805 \\
  = 0.62$

So this gives only a probability of 0.62, as opposed to 0.98, that at least 1 person out of 1000 will get all ten cards right.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If the $1000$ people made sure all their guesses were different, then the probability of one being correct would be $\frac{1000}{2^{10}}=0.9765625$.,and this is also the expected number of correct guesses even if each guess is independent.   It is the possibility that some may make the same guess as others which reduces the probability of at least one being correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 10 cards are picked randomly, your answer seems correct but a little cumbersome. The probability that one person wins is $$\frac{1}{2}^{10}$$

The probability that at least one person wins:

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{at least one wins})
&=1-P(\text{no one wins})\\
&=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}^{10}\right)^{1000}\\
&\approx 0.6235762
\end{align*}$$

This can be verified in R:

```
sum(dbinom(1:1000, 1000, .5^10))

0.6235762
```

Comment: Note that since $2^{10}\approx 1000$ and $1000$ is a decently large number, you can 'guess' even without doing the math that this will be pretty close to $1-e^{-1}\approx 0.632\ldots$, and indeed, it's less than $10^{-2}$ away...

Comment: That's a good find. In any case OP, I think we are either misinterpreting the question or they made an error.

Comment: having read the slide deck OP points to, I'm pretty sure they just made an error.